# xcode beta 3 swift and FBLoginViewDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

with the new release of xcode (beta 3) the class I implemented to handle facebook login in facebook doesn't work anymore. it failed to use FBLoginViewDelegate where before it worked. this happens when I use to extends a class:

```
class LoginVC: MyViewController,MyDetailUsable,FBLoginViewDelegate
```

I installed last facebook sdk,
Just in case I forgot something, this are my settings defined for the project:

```
MyConnection/MyConnection-Bridging-Header.h  : #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

//:configuration = Debug
SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = MyConnection/MyConnection-Bridging-Header.h

//:configuration = Release
SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = MyConnection/MyConnection-Bridging-Header.h

//:completeSettings = some
SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER = YES
//:configuration = Debug
CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = YES
//:configuration = Release
CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = YES
//:completeSettings = some
CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = YES
```

do you have any suggestion to avoid or solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook SDK has a protocol named `FBGraphObject` and also a classed named the same. In Swift the namespace of protocols and classes is unified so you can't have conflicting names. For this reason you can't use the precompiled Facebook library.

You need to rename the `FBGraphObject` protocol to something else like `FBGraphObjectProtocol` and compile the SDK yourself. This conflict will also cause SourceKitService most of the times.

I wrote about this on Apple dev forums and someone has forked the Facebook SDK to make the changes. If you're using Cocoapods you can use `pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', :git => 'https://github.com/pgaspar/facebook-ios-sdk.git'` or download the source code yourself and make the changes.

Comment: thanks E.Parto. Do you have a quick link pointing to the post? just to go little deeper

Comment: found it. [facebook sdk fork](https://github.com/pgaspar/facebook-ios-sdk). I'll try it an I'll let you know

Comment: Let me know if something goes wrong with the fork :)