# Facebook SDK in iOS 8 with Swift/Xcode beta 5 returning accessToken but no userID after update

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-ios-sdk, xcode6

After updating my project and setup to iOS 8 / Swift / Xcode beta 5, the Facebook iOS SDK no longer returns a `userID` from `accessTokenData.userID` when the Facebook App is installed (it is nil). This is happening when the state changes to `FBSessionStateOpen`. `accessTokenData.accessToken` *does* returns a value, and I'm fairly sure that access token is the same as the access token that the browser returns after I try signing in when the Facebook App is deleted. Everything works fine if I sign in with the browser, same account and everything.

Is this something that is on my end, or is it the Facebook iOS SDK not working anymore with the current status of the beta? And if so, should I ignore the issue above and continue development by only logging in through Safari, then revisit the issue when Facebook releases their official iOS 8 SDK update? I've noticed that they were putting out weekly updates, but now they have not updated for a month.

Answer (score 3):

Updating to this [forked Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/pgaspar/facebook-ios-sdk) solved my problem, and it seems to have solved another issue for someone else: [xcode beta 3 swift and FBLoginViewDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760097/xcode-beta-3-swift-and-fbloginviewdelegate?rq=1)